# How to create a Broacast intent to be called in onCreate?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

How would i go about calling an broadcast intent for this class. I want to create an intent to be called inside the onCreate Method so that it can send that broadcast Receiver.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg = "";

        if(bundle != null){
            //Do Nothing

        }else{
            checkMessage();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [sendBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) method. And in the Intent specify the class name of the receiver.

Comment: @adventej Because my broadcast receiver is in the same class as where i want to call it in the onCreate. It keeps giving me an syntax every time i try to call sendBroadcas(Receiver) in the onCreate Above.

Comment: How do you register the receiver ?